# i need a js decimel countdown which will not reset after browser refresh

Tags: javascript

I need a countdown which will start a decimal number and can't reset after refresh. exmaple: will be start with 10.7645343 and stop in 5000.. and it will be continue. but when browser refresh it will be not reset..

Comment: Then count down to a specific date in the future.

Comment: You could also start the countdown, and store the interval in a cookie or local storage.  BTW were you looking for a [Code Writing Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is client-side script language. Your defined variables, objects, functions etc. stored in user's browser. When you refresh the page, it will refresh everything.

Look here for more details about JavaScript [What is JavaScript? - Learn Web Development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/What_is_JavaScript)

If you want data that will not change when you refresh the page, you need to work with **Server Side Languages like PHP, ASP .Net** or **Server Side Frameworks for JavaScript like Node.JS**. Also you can store your datas in .txt files or .json files, after you can define this datas with **AJAX, XMLHttpRequest, Fetch** with JavaScript. But file management will expensive than other choices.